# How to get user information with Facebook PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use the Facebook API and I wish retrieve Facebook information of the connected user. I can retrieve the information in javascript, but I want to get the information to fill the PHP stored in my database.

Here is my code in javascript function:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Application</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            div { padding: 10px; }
        </style>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var fbAppId = 'myAppId';
          var objectToLike = 'http://techcrunch.com/2013/02/06/facebook-launches-developers-live-video-channel-to-keep-its-developer-ecosystem-up-to-date/';

          if (fbAppId === 'replace me') {
            alert('Please set the fbAppId in the sample.');
          }

          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : fbAppId,        // App ID
              status     : true,           // check login status
              cookie     : true,           // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true            // parse page for xfbml or html5 social plugins like login button below
            });

            FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                   window.alert(response.last_name + ', ' + response.first_name + ", " + response.email);
                 });
               }
             });
          };

          (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP code I can not make it work

```
<?php
require_once("php-sdk/facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'myAppId';
$config['secret'] = 'myCodeSecret';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$user = $facebook->getUser();

$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
?>
```

If I display the variable `$user`, I get my user id. But then I can not get other information.

I looked more in detail and this may be a problem in the configuration of the application in Facebook. Could you explain the steps to create an application on Facebook?

Comment: try to var_dump($user_profile); let's see what is response

Comment: that means your call failed, there might be something wrong in your code or parameters, did you set you login information correctly?

Comment: Yes, I think. When you speak of the connection information is just log on to Facebook?

Comment: you should configure those to match your api auth `$config['appId'] = 'myAppId';` and `$config['secret'] = 'myCodeSecret';`

Comment: yes, that part is good. I create an application on Facebook, then I took the ID App: App and Secret: then I insert in my code

Comment: In any case, as soon as I call getUser () function, I get an ID. So I do not think it comes information conntection

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30040/discussion-between-fabio-and-florent)

Comment: Where is your code for the login url that takes the scope permissions?

Comment: I have this code for scope permissions :

`$params = array(
              'scope' => 'read_stream, email',
              'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.mydomain.ch/index.php'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
print_r($user_profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a quick script which gets user data**

```
<?php     
try {
    // Get UID of the user
    $uid = $this->fb->getUser();

    // Get basic info about the user
    $me = $this->fb->api('/me');

    // Get the user's facebook stream
    $feed = $this->fb->api('/me/home');

    // Obtain user's and his/her friend's basic information via FQL Multiquery
    $streamQuery = <<<STREAMQUERY
{
"basicinfo": "SELECT uid,name,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid=me()",
"friendsinfo" : "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"
}
STREAMQUERY;
    $streamParams = array(
                          'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
                          'queries' => $streamQuery
                   );
    $streamResult = $this->fb->api($streamParams);

    //Obtain user likes, interests, movies, music, books
    $likes = $this->fb->api('/me/likes');
    $interests = $this->fb->api('/me/interests');
    $movies = $this->fb->api('/me/movies');
    $music = $this->fb->api('/me/music');
    $books = $this->fb->api('/me/books');
}catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    //Session expired or user de-authenticated the app
    $this->showConnectToFB(true);
}

?>
```

Comment: This still does not work.
There is a problem with the declaration of the variable $streamQuery

Comment: This should work fine. My guess is you or your text editor applied tabs or spaces before the content of the $streamQuery variable and this is what broke it. He is using heredoc notation to declare the string and there cannot be any space before the heredoc marker end tag (in this case, 'STREAMQUERY;').

Answer (score 0):

I'm now answering on an old thread but I was experience the same problem. I have solved this to creat a $params array with my acces token.

So the things to do is something like this.

```
    $config = array();
$config['appId'] = $appid;
$config['secret'] = $appSecret;
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$fb = new Facebook($config);

$params = array("access_token" => "acces_token_given_by_facebook");
$object = $fb->api('/me', 'GET', $params);

print_r($object);
```

When you add $params to your get request it will work. Facebook won't do anything untill you've sended the acces token. Also this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
// OR
// echo 'Name: ' . $user->getName();
```